# Функция которая получает строку и удаляет из нее символы

Tags: javascript

Вот само задание:

Написать функцию, которая получает в качестве аргумента строку и удаляет из нее символы,код которых больше 1103 или меньше 1040.
Функция должна вернуть новую строку
Применить эту функцию к строке

"Вчbvnера 789 был home work наiuyстоtящий + празrorднgfdик"

Есть набросок, но он не корректно работает:

```
function sliceChars(str) {
  var newStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var symbol = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (symbol < 1103 && symbol > 1040) {
      newStr += str[i];
    }
    if (symbol === 32) {
      newStr += " ";
      continue;
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}
console.log(
  sliceChars("Вчbvnера 789 был home work наiuyстоtящий + празrorднgfdик")
);
```

Прошу сделать только в виде функии. Или доделать данную, или написать с нуля.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: что именно некорректно в текущем варианте?

Comment: Возможно, лишние пробелы, остающиеся после удаления?

Comment: Судя по диапазону кодов, пробелы тоже нужно удалить...

Comment: Пробелы могут быть исключением, судя по дополнительному условию. Может, описание задачи сократили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ошибка в лишних пробелах, то можно исправить небольшим добавлением в условие:

```js
function sliceChars(str) {
  var newStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var symbol = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (symbol < 1103 && symbol > 1040) {
      newStr += str[i];
    }
    // Вот тут:
    if (symbol === 32 && newStr[newStr.length - 1] !== " ") {
      newStr += " ";
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}
console.log(
  sliceChars("Вчbvnера 789 был home work наiuyстоtящий + празrorднgfdик")
);
```

Comment: Да, ошибка была в лишних пробелах. Спасибо Вам большое!)

Answer (score 0):

:) Не разобрался сразу с вопросом. Вариант с удалением кодов символов.
Пробелы, как я понимаю, нужно оставить.

```js
function remove(str, start, end) {
  return str.replace(/[^\s]/g, (_) => {
    let n = _.charCodeAt()
    return (n < start || n > end) ? '' : _
  })
  // Вот это можно вставить для чистки лишних пробелов
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
}

const str = "Вчbvnера 789 был home work наiuyстоtящий + празrorднgfdик"
console.log(remove(str, 1040, 1103))
```

Это был первый вариант с удалением чисел. Оставлю его :)

```js
function remove(str, start, end) {
  return str.replace(/[0-9]+/g, (_) => {
    let n = Number.parseInt(_, 10)
    return (n < start || n > end) ? '' : _
  })
}

const str = "Вчbvnера 789 был home work наiuyстоtящий + празrorднgfdик"
const str2 = "Вчbvnера 1050 был home work наiuyстоtящий + празrorднgfdик"

console.log(remove(str, 1040, 1103))
console.log(remove(str2, 1040, 1103))
```

Comment: Кажется, подразумевались коды Юникода, а не цифры.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty да уж, плохо когда занимаешься двумя делами. Я этого даже не заметил. Спасибо :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, за Ваш ответ!)